# Is every homotopy equivalence a fibration over the interval?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, homotopy-type-theory

It is a well known fact from homotopy theory that if $X\to Y$ is a Hurewicz fibration and  $y_0,y_1$ are two points of $Y$ connected by a path $y_0\sim y_1$, then the fibers over $y_0$ and $y_1$ are homotopy equivalent. I wondered whether the converse holds. More precisely:

> Let $X,Y$ be homotopically equivalent topological spaces. Does there exist a Hurewicz fibration $\pi:E\to I=[0,1]$, such that $\pi^{-1}(0)=X$ and $\pi^{-1}(1)=Y$?

If you wish, you can make any homotopically insignificant assumptions, for example that $X,Y$ are well-pointed CW-complexes.

I tried using the fact that two homotopically equivalent spaces are deformation retracts of the same space, but didn't succeed.

Motivation for the question comes from homotopy type theory. It is one of possible interpretations of the univalence axiom in topology. In homotopy type theory univalence asserts that equivalences are exactly paths in the universe. Since paths are maps from the interval, a path in the universe, hence an equivalence, is the same as a fibration over the interval.

Comment: Given a map $f:X\rightarrow Y$, you can get something by taking the obvious projection $\pi:M_f\rightarrow I$, where $M_f$ is the mapping cylinder of $f$. The map $\pi$ will be a *quasifibration* whenever $f$ is a *weak* homotopy equivalence. Some details are found on pg.479 of Hatcher's book. Hatcher points out that $\pi$ will generally fail to be even a Serre fibration.

Comment: This is a very good question that I'm sure has been written about. I would like to say there have to be obvious counterexamples, like if $X=*$ and $Y$ is a contractible space with incredibly huge cardinality.